# How to get this UIBarButtonItem in the picture?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I want to get a button with short lines on `UINavigationBar`.

Please, see that on this image:

[image]

What is it? How to get it?

Comment: You need to make the image yourself, as that isn't an iOS provided image/UIBarButtonItem

Comment: Maybe you'll find what you want on The Noun Project: http://thenounproject.com/search/?q=menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to instantiate a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image_filename"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTappedMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

This creates a `UIButton` with a supplied image. That `UIButton` is then set as a custom view for a `UIBarButtonItem`. Then, just set the barButtonItem on your navigation item.